# How to prevent creating fake $_GET values by user?

Tags: php, get

I've been creating my first big project in PHP OOP.
When user submits the dynamically-created form, data are saved in `$_GET` array (va, vb, vc, vd).
But number of text inputs in this form depends on the database result (it may be only va, may be va and vb, may be va, vb and vc and so on). These values are necessary to make calculations.
The problem is - what if user forge these `$_GET` elements changing name of text inputs or link? The calculations will be wrong, or they will return error.
I tried to save correct elements while creating dynamic form and then compare it with `$_GET` elements like this:

```
foreach ($_GET as $value) {
    $search = false;
    foreach ($_SESSION['correctVars'] as $var) {
        if (array_key_exists($var, $_GET)) {
            $search = true;
        }
    }
    if ($search === false) {
        exit('WRONG DATA');
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: you get the key and just use `in_array()` and wollah! No need for more than one loop :)

Answer (score 0):

its early, i may be missing a better idea but:

```
$_GET = array('va'=>'1', 'vb'=>'7' );

$correctVars = array('va', 'vb', 'vc', 'vd');

$x=count(array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip($correctVars))); 

if($x != count($_GET)){
    echo 'bad data';
}
```

we get a count of the keys in get that are also allowed. if the count of all get does not match that, something is wrong with the data.

you can test it by testing the 2 get array versions here: http://ideone.com/v2sUv1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_diff` to get only invalid keys and then do what you want, in my example I tell the user these params are phoney, but you can use the logic to `die()` or relocate etc. etc.

```
<?php
    # input url -> localhost/index.php?trey=awesome&bake=not&mum=cool
    $getKeys = array_keys($_GET);
    $allowedKeys = ['mum'];

    $diff = array_diff($getKeys, $allowedKeys);

    if (count($diff) > 0) {
        echo 'Bad params: '. implode(', ', $diff);
    }
```

`array_diff()` will return an array of non-matches, meaning we can track what's "fake".

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think I found an easier way with foreach but yours also looks great. What do you think about ```$i = 0;
  foreach ($_GET as $value => $k) {
   if (!isset($correct[$i]) || $value != $correct[$i]) {
    return Constants::GETVALS_ERR;
   }
   $i++;
  }
  return true;``` where $correct is array with correct GET values.

Comment: meh, I personally wouldn't go for that, but what you decide to do is down to you :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you go for that?

Comment: @mystickGuy I just prefer using the `array_` functions, as little loops as possible :)